# use func to alternative either task a or b every time it is called

Tags: swift, counter, var, func, alternate

This is in switft code. I would like to change the background color a button that is currently red to blue. However it tapped again I would like it to change from blue to red. How I normally would do this would be.

```
var counter = 0
var button = UIButton()

func switch(){
if counter % 2 == 0 {
  button.backgroundcolor = .blue
  }
    else {
    button.backgroundcolor = .red }
   counter += 1}
```

I am writing this question because although what I am doing is working. I am thinking there has to be a more efficient way to write code instead of declaring a var and diving it.

Comment: Why do you need counter? Just check current background color of button and change accordingly

Comment: For one, don't write `x % y == 0`, just use `x.isMultiple(of: y)`

Comment: @adnbsr I need the counter to be able to switch the task. The function should just do 1 of 2 tasks every time it is called. It does the opposite tasks from the task it last did. So func is called blue func is called again red.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica can you write that in a answer never seen that before.

Comment: Nah, it's not an answer, just a comment on this particular approach. If I were to write an answer, it wouldn't be to use this counter. I assume that this code is in your ViewController (given that you're accessing `button.backgroundColor`, not `self.backgroundColor`, so I presume `button` is a `UIButton` member of your VC). Instead, make a `UIButton` subclass, which has a `toggle` method which automatically changes its colour back and forth.

Comment: @maxSmtih Yep, I guess correctly

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica can you write that answer on how to subclass with a toggle method. Have not scene that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are only two states declare `counter` as Bool

```
var backgroundColorIsBlue = false
```

In the `switch` function – which doesn't compile because `switch` is a reserved word – just toggle (invert) the Bool and set the background color. The ternary operator uses the value after the `?` if `backgroundColorIsBlue` is `true` otherwise the value after the `:`.

```
@objc func switchAction(_ sender : UIButton) {
    backgroundColorIsBlue.toggle()
    sender.backgroundColor = backgroundColorIsBlue ? .blue : .red
}
```